# Retrieve value in JSON from pandas series object

Tags: python, json, pandas, series

I need help retrieving a value from a JSON response object in python. Specifically, how do I access the prices-asks-price value? I'm having trouble:

JSON object:

```
{'prices': [{'asks': [{'liquidity': 10000000, 'price': '1.16049'}],
   'bids': [{'liquidity': 10000000, 'price': '1.15989'}],
   'closeoutAsk': '1.16064',
   'closeoutBid': '1.15974',
   'instrument': 'EUR_USD',
   'quoteHomeConversionFactors': {'negativeUnits': '1.00000000',
    'positiveUnits': '1.00000000'},
   'status': 'non-tradeable',
   'time': '2018-08-31T20:59:57.748335979Z',
   'tradeable': False,
   'type': 'PRICE',
   'unitsAvailable': {'default': {'long': '4063619', 'short': '4063619'},
'openOnly': {'long': '4063619', 'short': '4063619'},
'reduceFirst': {'long': '4063619', 'short': '4063619'},
'reduceOnly': {'long': '0', 'short': '0'}}}],
 'time': '2018-09-02T18:56:45.022341038Z'}
```

Code:

```
data = pd.io.json.json_normalize(response['prices'])
asks = data['asks']
asks[0]

Out: [{'liquidity': 10000000, 'price': '1.16049'}]
```

I want to get the value 1.16049 - but having trouble after trying different things.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

asks[0] returns a list so you might do something like

> ```
> asks[0][0]['price']
> ```

or

> ```
> data = pd.io.json.json_normalize(response['prices'])
> price = data['asks'][0][0]['price']
> ```

Answer (score 0):

The data that you have contains `jsons` and `lists` inside one another. Hence you need to navigate through this accordingly. Lists are accessed through `indexes` (starting from 0) and jsons are accessed through `keys`.

```
   price_value=data['prices'][0]['asks'][0]['price']
   liquidity_value=data['prices'][0]['asks'][0]['liquidity']
```

Explaining this logic in this case : I assume that your big json object is stored in a object called data. First accessing `prices` key in this object. Then I have `index 0` because the next key is present inside a `list`. Then after you go inside the list, you have a key called `asks`. Now again you have a list here so you need to access it using `index 0`. Then finally the key `liquidity` and `price` is here.